# При обновлении страницы в Swiper слайдер10 мигает первый слайд

Tags: wordpress, swiper

Сайт на Wordpress
На странице установлен Swiper слайдер 10.
На страницу слайдер выводится повторителем ACF
Изначально выводится 4 слайда.
В момент загрузки/обновления страницы на долю секунды всплывает 1-й слайд на всю ширину слайдера.
Затем все приходит в норму.
Как избавиться от этого глюка?
Страница: https://biz-vip.ru/blago/
Параметры слайдера:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        slidesPerView: 4,
        spaceBetween: 10,
        loop: true,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
            breakpoints: {
            // when window width is >= 320px
            320: {
              slidesPerView: 1,
            },
            // when window width is >= 480px
            480: {
              slidesPerView: 1,
            },
            // when window width is >= 640px
            640: {
              slidesPerView: "4", 
            }
        },
        
            
      });
```

Comment: Это не относится к Вашей конфигурации свайпера. Лично у меня нет той проблемы что Вы описали, но у Вас в принципе есть заметный layout shift, пока не подгрузятся шрифты.

Comment: Но обычно такие вещи происходят когда браузер отображает элементы страницы до того, как CSS или JavaScript полностью загружены и применены к этим элементам. Скорее всего получается что браузер рендерит слайдер перед тем, как Swiper загрузится и будет инициализирован.

Answer (score 0):

Разбираясь глубже, выяснил следующее:

В файле стилей слайдера изначально задана ширина слайда :100%
Этот файл грузится из CDN, и править его возможности нет.
В скрипте инициализации слайдера у меня указан вывод на странице 4-х слайдов.
Этот скрипт грузится после файла стилей.
Поэтому и происходит мигание первого слайда на всю ширину.

Я задал слайдеру opacity: 0. Но добавил скрипт отложенного изменения opacity на 1. Таким образом глюк происходит в скрытом режиме.

```js
    <script>    
      setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('swiper').style.opacity = 1;
      },
      100);
    </script>
```

Решение , конечно, костыльное, но, по-моему, вполне жизнеспособное, и ни на что не влияющее.

Есть мнения?

Comment: Имело бы смысл это делать на [init ивент свайпера](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#events)